# Add color filter over IconCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, slice, porter-duff

I'm using a custom closed-source (not very well documented) library to create some Android Slices. For this I have to use `IconCompat` in order to load some icons in the slice. I would like to change the colours of these icons dynamically based on some backend data.

Tried doing it like so but the icon is still white regardless:

```
   val icon = IconCompat.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.calendar_slice_color)
   icon.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP)
   icon.setTint(event.color)
```

Any idea how to apply the `color.event` over the `IconCompat` before sending it to the slice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

icon.mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that since my icon is of type `IconCompat` and not `Drawable`

Comment: I need it as `IconCompat` in order to pass it to the library and even if I load it as `Drawable` from resources, I didn't find any way to convert it from `IconCompat` afterwards